# Is there a way to find the on-screen coordinates of an ImageView's drawable?

Tags: android, imageview, drawable

I have an activity which consists of just an ImageView. The drawable contained in the ImageView is a Bitmap that was captured from the camera. The image is automatically scaled (maintaining the Bitmap's aspect ratio) so that the scaled width matches the width of the ImageView, and the image is centered on the screen vertically.

I need to figure out the coordinates of the top-left pixel of the actual drawable (not of the ImageView itself), but the ImageView class doesn't seem to give me a way of doing that.

I feel like I could potentially calculate it based on the dimensions of the original bitmap and the dimensions of the ImageView, but that would involve a lot of math that should be unnecessary, and would be prone to floating point errors.

Does anyone know of a way to find the coordinates of the top-left pixel of the Drawable relative to the ImageView?

Thanks.

Comment: I am not 100% positive, but I think the only thing you can retrieve are the top and left positions of the ImageView, not the actual image. Maybe try calling the getPadding() methods and subtracting / adding the result to the position of the ImageView? My gut tells me those are going to return 0 though.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [**ImageView**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) source code, [it translates a Matrix halfway the vertical size](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2.1_r1/android/widget/ImageView.java#ImageView.configureBounds%28%29) (i.e., center it vertically), so you could retrieve it with the `ImageView` [`getImageMatrix()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#getImageMatrix%28%29) method and check the vertical translation by [`Matrix#getValues(float[])`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html#getValues%28float%5b%5d%29). If I read it right, it will be [the sixth value](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html#MTRANS_Y).

I can't test it right now, but it would be something like:

```
Matrix matrix = iv.getImageMatrix ();
float[] values = new float[];
matrix.getValues(values);
float startY = values[5];
```